# Why .animate is so slow in IE 8

Tags: jquery

this is my animate Code

```
    function MoveTeleport(LeftRight,UpDown) {
        var TileMoveLeft = new Number(-LeftRight);
        var TileMoveUp = new Number(-UpDown);
        this.MovetoLeft = TileMoveLeft * 70 + 'px';
        this.MovetoUp = TileMoveUp * 70 + 'px';

        this.Move = function () {
            $('#Player').fadeTo(200,0.1);

            $('#Map_Player').animate({
                'left': '+=' + this.MovetoLeft,
                'top': '+=' + this.MovetoUp
            }, 1000, function () {
                LeftCurrent = $('#Map_Player').css('left', 10);
                UpCurrent = $('#Map_Player').css('top', 10);
                $('#Player').fadeTo(200, 1);
            });
        }
    }
```

it Animated so nice in FireFox,Opera,Chrome . but in IE8 it does'nt work well , any idea why ??or how to fix it in IE 8 ??

Comment: This is a hard question to answer without seeing what you are trying to animate. Could you post more code or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: For Moving  the Item i just do this 

var Player1Teleport = new MoveTeleport($('#TxtLeft').val(),$('#TxtUp').val());
Player1Teleport.Move();

Comment: See this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164101/slow-jquery-animation-in-ie

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's `.animate` and other similar methods recalculate a DOM element's CSS each frame, then update the element's `style` property. Each frame, the browser needs to recalculate the site layout and render it. In certain cases the animation might require expensive layout recalculation (depends on how the site elements are laid out, on your CSS, etc.). IE8 has a rather old rendering engine and I would wager the layout recalculation in your case is just too expensive for it. There's no way to fix that other than getting rid of the `.animate`.

The issue of `.animate` performance has been mentioned in an [article on Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/) yesterday - it might be an interesting thing to read.